# Rails_admin, List of models show zero when using cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, rails-admin, cancancan

I have models `Owner`, `Shop` and `Item`.

`Owner` has many `Shops` and `Shops` has many `Items`.

My ability on Cancan:

```
can :manage, Shop, owner_id: user.id
can :manage, Item, shop: {owner_id: user.id}
```

When I open my rails_admin dashboard, it says that I have zero `Items` and page `List of Items` is empty.

However, when I open Shops page, I can see all its Items and I can change them on Shops page.

When I write my code like this:

```
  can :manage, Item do |item|
    item.shop.owner_id == user.id
  end
```

It throws me an error:

```
The accessible_by call cannot be used with a block 'can' definition. The SQL cannot be determined for :index Item
```

Why I can't list all my `Items` on `Items List`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one solution.

I need to add additinal field to my `Item` model:

```
field :shop_owner_id, type: String
```

Then I need to assign it:

```
 before_save :set_shop_owner_id

 def set_shop_owner_id
   self.shop_owner_id = self.shop.owner.id.to_s
 end
```

In my `ability.rb` file I needed to add this:

```
can :manage, Item, shop_owner_id: user.id
```

Which means, there is some kind of error when `rails_admin` wnats to index all items, which belongs to shop that belongs to current owner. This helps to avoid it.

Not good solution I think, but works.